# Why some trainers don't want to train me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The first time I played Skyrim was with a female Nord, and I was able to train One Handed and Smithing with Amrem and Ghorza. The second time I played with a female Imperial, I beat their quests but they didn't offer me the option to train. After that I played with a female Redguard and another female Nord character and I was able to train with them. Does anyone knows why his happened?

Comment: These NPCs don't give you the option to level up, it just happens automatically. It might be possible that you missed the notification/it didn't appear? Check your skill levels and see if they did change

Comment: Sorry but the training option doesn't show in the dialog box, I have the regular topics but "I'd like to train in One Handed" never shows, for example. This only happened with my Imperial character.

Comment: Again, this is because they do not give you the option. This happens automatically as a quest reward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is all because patches.
If you remember, in first versions of Skyrim you could take Faendal as your companion, train Archery with him and take your money back from his inventory.
Later on this was removed.
Same stuff with it.
Also, some NPC's are eligible to train you only if you play certain species and gender. Read the NPC's description on wiki, you'll find the full info about any NPC in Skyrim.

Comment: Done, I cheked on UESP and found about this situation, thanks for the answer

Comment: @Ethan Great! I'm glad I could help! :)